# error en Datepicker

Tags: visual-studio

Señores  buenas nochs, por que cuando intento obtener los registros de un usuario  que su campo fechanacimento es vacio me revienta el programa y me sale este error el valor de '1/1/0001' 12:00:00AM no es valido para 'value'. 'value'deberia estar estar entre 'minDate' y maxDate', eh intentado que cuando fecha sea igual a null el datepiker se ponga en blanco pero no me funciono

clientes.FechaNacimiento = dtpFecha.Text;
            dtpFecha.CustomFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy";
            dtpFecha.CustomFormat = "";

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Los errores deben ir como texto, como asi tambien el codigo que causa el error. No podes no ponerle valor a dtp. Estos siempre llevan una fecha....

Comment: El código relevante debe ir en tu pregunta. Usa la opción de editar e inclúyelo, por favor.

Answer (score 0):

Deberias establecer un valor por defecto cuando no tiene fecha en el registro. Cuando es nulo.. no intentar convertir un nulo a fecha.